No denoiser, how can I install one?
I am running Blender 3.4 on Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm).
Each time, I begin a new blend file, denoiser is checked in render settings.
But if I try to render, render result comes to be completely transparent and empty, and there is an error, "built without OpenImage denoiser." I thought it may be due to the fact that denoiser option is empty, so I unchecked denoiser, and it renders, but I cannot denoise anything. Do I have to install a denoiser to make it work? What denoiser?


Download an up to date official build from the official website with all the features, rather than an outdated feature crippled version from the repository

Is there a Blender repo that I get updates from easily? How can I be informed about updates, @DuarteFarrajotaRamos ?

I solved it thanks to the comment of @DuarteFarrajotaRamos :
Download an up to date official build from the official website with all the features, rather than an outdated feature crippled version from the repository
